# Take a cube, add one, when is this a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Take 
$$
p = n^3 + 1
$$

I just realised, checking some numbers, that this only occurs for $n=1$. I was wondering if there is some general proof for this?

Comment: $n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can factorize $n^3+1$, so: $$ p= (n+1)(n^2-n+1)$$ so $n+1 = 1$ (so $n=0$) or $n^2-n+1=1$ (so $n(n-1)=0$...)

Comment: As an extension to this, $n^2 - 1$ is also never a prime unless $n=2$. Is there a general proof for $p = n^y + z$, more specifically between $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Heck of a "hint".

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that $n+1$ or $n^2 - n + 1$ could be $-1$, although in this case that doesn't add solutions.

Comment: To the proposer:  Regarding $n^y+z$ in general I'm pretty sure there isn't any known general  method. I think that even the case $n^2+1$ is unsolved.  But if $z=1$ and if $y$ is divisible by an odd prime $p$ then the number $n^y+z=n^y+1$ has $n^{y/p}+1$ as a factor by the same method as in this Answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your understanding stronger by the fact for any odd number $k > 1$ and $n > 1$, the number $p = n^k + 1$ is never a prime because it is divisible by $n+1$. The cubes or $k = 3$ is a special case of this.

Comment: but $p = 1^k + 1$ is prime for all $k$.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: O my god its so non trivial